# how to divide the given sample into classes

Tags: statistics

Given a list of numbers: $9,10,52,57,62,62,62,65,66,67,68,68,68,69,69,69,71,71,72,72,73,74,74,75,75,75,76,77,78,79,79,79,80,80,82,83,85,88,89,91,93,97,97,97,98,99,101,104,105,105$

$a)$ divide into classes

My attemp is:

$a)$ The total number of the list is $n=51$

I find the range of the list: $Rang(X)=96.$ Lower class limit of a first class is $9$

$classes=\sqrt n\approx 7$ or $8$, becuouse $49<51<64$

$class width=\frac{Range(X)}{class}=12$

For this reason I have divided this list into these classes:

$9-20(frequence 2), 21-32 (0),33-44(0),45-56(1),57-68(11),69-80(21),81-92(6),93-105(10)$

I don't know if I did well to divide the classes. Help me please

Comment: I think you may also need to put the actual data into those classes, and perhaps say how may are in each class

Comment: sir Henry, think about the frequency in each class or not, i edited my asnwer

Comment: can someone tell me if i did well the class division, or should I do another class division, ex. divide a class $9-44 (frequence 2), 45-80 (frequence 33), 81-105 (frequence 16)$

Comment: "Classes" is a generic term used to mean many, many different things in mathematics. What do you mean by "classes" here?